# How to extract a figure from a long line of text with different kinds of characters using REGEXREPLACE in ACL (Highbond)

Tags: sql, regex, acl, regex-replace

I have strings in this format in a column called "Charge_Details" with minor differences: SBLC FEE
<> 1 - 360 day*!<> 400,000.00 USD<> 08/02/18 - 17/12/18  312 <>9

I'm trying to extract the amount before USD using REGEX functions. The application I'm using (ACL from Highbond) only has REGEXFIND and REGEXREPLACE with these syntaxes: REGEXFIND(string, pattern) and REGEXREPLACE(string, pattern, new_string) functions.
You can ignore the ACL scripting parts of this request. I just need help with the REGEX part.

It uses the same REGEX rules as with any other application.

I have tried removing the "<<>>" and then trying to return only the amount to no avail.

I first created another column (CATEGORY) replacing all the "<>" with "++" and "||" and excluding "*!"
EXCLUDE( ALL(REGEXREPLACE(ALL(REGEXREPLACE(charge_details,"<<(\w\w\w\w)>>\s\d{1,2}/\d\d/\d\d", "++")), "<<(\w\w\w\w)>>", "||")), "*!") IF FIND("!", CHARGE_DETAILS)

The result: SBLC FEE|| 1 - 360 day|| 400,000.00 USD++ - 17/12/18  312 ||9

When I try to split the new string column using the "||" as a delimiter, it only returns "SBLC FEE" in the first segment and blanks in any other segment.

I then tried to extract the amount from the CATEGORY column I created using:
REGEXREPLACE(CATEGORY, "(\d{0,3})(,\d{3})*(.\d\d)(\s\w\w\w)|)","$1$2$3$4")

It just returns everything in the CATEGORY column instead of the four groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your data always in a consistent format, where the dollar amount is in the 3rd "position" of your string?

Comment: Are you just looking for numbers that come before "USD" or are there instances of that that you would want to exclude?

Comment: @Isolated for the a large number of the lines, yes. Sometimes it's in the 2nd or fourth position.

Comment: @CAustin Yes. I'm just looking for the numbers before USD.

Comment: Then that's quite simple, no need to mess with the delimiters https://regex101.com/r/bPigyS/1

Comment: @CAustin the link shows how I can represent the pattern relating to 400,000.00. I want a pattern that will represent everything before and after 400,00.00 which I can then replace with just the pattern representing 400,00.00.

The application I'm using only allows this input: REGEXREPLACE(string, pattern, new_string)

Comment: @EmmanuelSalau Then just surround the pattern in parentheses and put `.*` on either side

Comment: I think the issue is with the ACL application from Highbond and how REGEX is implemented in it. That didn't work either. Finally figured something out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This example is in Oracle, but should help you with the regex.  The WITH clause just sets up test data.  The regex says, match zero or more characters followed by a space followed by one or more digits which are followed by zero or more characters (non-greedily) until followed by the literal 'spaceUSD' then anything else.  Note the parens around the 'digits which are followed by zero or more characters' part.  That signifies a "remembered" group.  Replace the entire string with the remembered group #1.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'SBLC FEE <> 1 - 360 day*!<> 400,000.00 USD<> 08/02/18 - 17/12/18 312 <>9'
   from dual
 )
 select regexp_replace(str, '.* (\d+.*?) USD.*', '\1') as USD
 from tbl;


USD       
----------
400,000.00
1 row selected.
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. So I tried this but the application I'm using just goes ahead and returns the same thing whilst using the dotall. It excludes USD though as it's not part of the group.

Here's what it returned: SBLC FEE<<CHIB>> 1 - 360 day*!400,000.00<<CHPE>> 08/02/18 -02/02/19  359 <<DAY2>>9

Comment: I'll import the table into SSMS and see if I can make it work this way. I made these adjustments in ACL and it works fine now:

REGEXREPLACE(columnwithstrings, '[\w\W]* (\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?) (\w{3}?)[\w\W]*', "$1")

ACL views \1 as recurrence (that's why I used the $1 instead) and there are other currencies (hence the \w{3}). \w is any word character and \W is any non-word character. Don't know if that's the same in other applications. First time using REGEX functions tonight. Thanks a lot for your input. Definitely pointed me in the right direction.